# How to use join for more than two table?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have three tables.They are

**tb_albums**`---->id,title, description`

**tb_photos**`---->id,album_id, photo`

**tb_tags**`---->id,album_id, tag`

Here i want to get the albums details and it photos & it tags through **tb_albums.id**.

How to use join query here?

Comment: and what finally do you want to get? album row with its tags and photos count?

Comment: Please provide a sample of every table *and* what result you would expect based on them.

Answer (score 1):

Normally, you can use as many tables in JOIN, as you'd like. Just add another JOIN statement. You can refer to [k102's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6438903/how-to-use-join-for-more-than-two-table/6438992#6438992) for the correct syntax (which doesn't produce correct result though).

But in this particular case you don't want to use simple JOIN on all tables, unless you have only one photo per album and only one tag per album. If you have more than one photo per and more than one tag per album, JOIN both tables on album_id in single query will produce Cartesian product of both, in other words all possible combinations of tags and photos from each albums. For `N` photos and `M` tags that's `N * M` results, instead of `N + M`.

Also, there is no point of joining with tb_albums, as you do not need to repeat information about each album for each photo and each tag.

Proper approach would be to have 3 separate simple SELECTs from each table and combining their result on application level.

If for some awkward reason you'd need to do that with one query, you can do something like:

```
SELECT * FROM tb_albums as A JOIN 
 (SELECT 'photo', id, photo as value FROM tb_photos 
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'tag', id, tag as value FROM tb_tags) as B ON B.album_id = A.id
```

Note, this is way less optimal than separate SELECTs, you should only do this if you have no other choice.

Comment: How will one get album details **and its photos and its tags** without joining?

Comment: Despite your efforts, I'll restrain my urge to downvote your answer.

Comment: @ypercube: Apparently @vartec means 3 separate selects instead of a 3-table join.

Comment: @vartec: Possibly. Still, you should probably control your temper, even though I'm not your father. :)

Comment: @vartec, @Andriy: the issue is not to be obvious to anyone who knows SQL but to the ones (like OP) who are just starting to learn SQL and don't even know the JOIN syntax. This answer is pretty much useless in that matter.

Comment: @vartec: Well, there still are plenty of questions demanding a much higher level of expertise, you could just concentrate on them and omit beginners' questions altogether. Your answer is indeed incomplete. SO is great because of the answers that *explain* things. Yours doesn't. It only says: 'don't do that', but doesn't explain why. If a person asks how to join more than two tables, then they might not know what Cartesian product is.

Comment: Don't have MySQL to test this, but I think `A` can't be accessed from within the subselect. It definitely isn't accessible in SQL Server. Another thing is, you could use UNION ALL instead of UNION to avoid the unnecessary distinct sort.

Comment: @Andriy: In MySQL it can. One of the examples from MySQL manual: `SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT id FROM t2 WHERE t1.id=t2.id);`. Added ALL as you suggested

Comment: @vartec: In that example an alias is being accessed in the WHERE clause, which is all right in SQL Server also. In your case the alias is being accessed from within a 'sibling' subselect, which is very different. Did you try your query?

Comment: It's not valid SQL syntax as @Andriy points. But it definitely explains why the JOINs should be avoided in this case.

Comment: @Andriy: I'm not 100% sure, but AFAIR, this was possible with MySQL 5.5, indeed in 5.1 it doesn't work. Updated the SQL.

Comment: @ypercube: Good point. I like the way it unfolded. First it was shown that a simple join could not produce a correct output. Next it was demonstrated that a correct join could not be 'simple'.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from tb_albums a
join tb_photos p on a.id = p.album_id
join tb_tags t on a.id = t.album_id
```

Comment: So let's say you have 10 albums, each with 10 photos, and 10 tags. Result set of your query is 1000 rows, which is quite useless

Comment: Your definition of 'quite useless' is predicated on a client application that can't handle normalised data.  I find that I write my client apps in languages that are quite adept at loops...

Comment: @vartec did you see the question? "How to use join query here?" so, this is how to use join here.

Comment: @k: the question is **not** "how to write syntactically correct JOIN to get some useless data?".

Comment: I'm sure MS, Oracle, MySQL, TeraData and IBM would all love to know what their products really are then?  But as an aside; Why are you trying to be so offensive in you comments?  What is your logical criticism of returning normalised data to the client side?  Why are multiple record-sets better (including the case where the data is returned for multiple photos, requiring nested loops over the three record sets), or why would PIVOTed data be better/worse?

Comment: Useless data?  Please could you elaborate on why you believe it to be useless.

Comment: @Dems: I've said real databases, not real database engines. You know, like few million rows, not the thing you're toying around in Excel. Normalized data? Since when returning **duplicate** data is normalized? Since when returning 1000 rows for 200 rows worth of data is optimal? Since when loop `for (i=0;i<x*y*z; i++)` is shorter than loop `for (i=0;i<x;i++) {for(j=0;j<y;j++);for(j=0;j<z;j++)}`?

Comment: Name me one single corporate who would buy TeraData for sub-million-record databases?

Comment: @Dems: name single corporation who'd use your SQL to retrieve trillion rows and loop though them in the application